# Issue with For loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm a beginner and have issue with this program. I'm trying to read the form properties from a text file. Unfortunately it executes only the last line

this is my text file

```
PDR
1   4   200 200 30  60  UserId  
2   0   300 200 30  100 UserId 
3   1   350 350 30  70  Log In
```

AND THE CONSTRUCTOR that loads the form properties

```
public Form()
{
    {
        string fn = Path.Combine(path, "Login.Production.txt");
        string[] line;
        if (File.Exists(fn))
        {
            try
            {
                line = File.ReadAllLines(fn);
                string title = line[0];
                if (title == "PDR")
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string[] pty = line[i].Split('\t');
                        Items = new List<IFormItem>();
                        Items.Add(new FormItem());

                        foreach (FormItem fi in Items)
                        {
                            fi.Type = (ItemTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemTypes), pty[1]);
                            fi.Id = Convert.ToInt32(pty[0]);
                            fi.X = int.Parse(pty[2]);
                            fi.Y = Convert.ToInt32(pty[3]);
                            fi.Height = Convert.ToInt32(pty[4]);
                            fi.Width = Convert.ToInt32(pty[5]);
                            fi.Text = pty[6].ToLower();
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("The file is not cofigured.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The file was not found.", fn);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: C&P error? what is `i`?

Comment: `Items.Add(new FormItem());` you add only 1 item to this list and then loop through it? that does not make sense and it is also not clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Seems you're adding `Items.Add(new FormItem());` only once and then looping to insert into this location and as a matter of fact, it is overiting the previous data on each loop

Comment: you create `Items` on every iteration, put `Items = new List<IFormItem>();` outside `for`

Comment: @Grundy I shifted   Items = new List<IFormItem>();
                        Items.Add(new FormItem()); outside the for loop but still remains the same

Comment: Only the first for loop is enough. Keep statement " Items = new List<IFormItem>()"   outside the for loop and no need for the for each. Just iterate through each line and and read each entry by splitting by '\t'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're assigning `Items` to a new object for each line of the input file; another is that you're iterating over each element of `Items` for each line of input. Here's one way to fix it:

```
            if (title == "PDR")
            {
                Items = new List<IFormItem>();
                for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] pty = line[i].Split('\t');
                    FormItem fi = new FormItem();
                    Items.Add(fi);

                    fi.Type = (ItemTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemTypes), pty[1]);
                    fi.Id = Convert.ToInt32(pty[0]);
                    fi.X = int.Parse(pty[2]);
                    fi.Y = Convert.ToInt32(pty[3]);
                    fi.Height = Convert.ToInt32(pty[4]);
                    fi.Width = Convert.ToInt32(pty[5]);
                    fi.Text = pty[6].ToLower();
                }
            }
```

Another way to do it is with LINQ:

```
Items = (from l in line.Skip(1)
         let pty = l.Split('\t')
         select new FormItem
         {
             Type = (ItemTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemTypes), pty[1]),
             Id = int.Parse(pty[0]),
             X = int.Parse(pty[2]),
             Y = int.Parse(pty[3]),
             Height = int.Parse(pty[4]),
             Width = int.Parse(pty[5]),
             Text = pty[6].ToLower()
         }).ToList<IFormItem>();
```